# Transform list of complex objects to flatt list with LINQ

Tags: linq, object

I have List of Vehicle as shown bellow. I want to show this in CSV file, so in order to do this i would like to flatten this list:

```
 class Vehicle
{
    int vid;
    string name;
    string desc;
    CarType car;
    TruckType truck;
    TankType tank;       
}

class CarType
{
    int id;
    string color;
    string manual;
    string model;      
}

class TruckType
{
    int id;
    string width;
    string heigh;       
}

class TankType
{
    int id;
    string color;
    string size;       
}
```

How to get all properties (including those in the complex properties) into flat list.
How to do it with linq?

Comment: why do you think you need all those properties "flattened" ? It wouldn't make a difference if you write your own CSV writing code anyway

Comment: I have already extension method which using reflection. I do: MyObject.ToCSV() and it creates a CSV with all properties, but does not work with a complex properties.

Comment: It seems that XML would be a better solution than CSV

Comment: @user224763: well, what you're asking about is definitely doable, but how are you (or your client) going to deserialize the CSV file back to your `Vehicle` class? It's going to be very fragile, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create an anonymous object with all the flatten fields, supposing they are public.

```
var flat = vehicles.Select(x => new {
    vid = x.vid,
    name = x.name,
    desc = x.desc,
    carId = x.car.id,
    carColor = x.car.color;
    carManual = x.car.manual;
    carModel = x.car.model; 
    truckId = x.truck.id,
    truckWidth = x.truck.width,
    truckHeigh = x.truck.heigh,
    tankId = x.tank.id,
    tankColor = x.tank.color,
    tankSize = x.tank.size
});
```

By the way, you should use properties and not expose the fields.